# Onepage checkout always redirects to cart with custom step

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I'm having trouble with creating a custom step for magento onepage checkout. 
Link of the tutorial: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step .
The problem is, when I click 'continue' button on my custom step, it always redirects back to the cart page. Looking for help. Any suggestions how to debug redirecting? or how to see where is the problem. I've checked log files, it doesn't say anything in there. Where to start looking for problems? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: finally after long hours of searching, I found that I need to add following to my config.xml file.
<routers>
  <mymodel>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
      <module>Mymodule_Name</module>
      <frontName>mymodel</frontName>
    </args>
  </mymodel
</routers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check ajax calls in firebug, click on the "Net" tab. Something is wrong in your new step that's why it is failing.

Comment: I did everything exactly like in the tutorial. What should I look for in the Net tab?

Comment: it shows the requests. sometimes you'll not find ajax calls in Console but will be there in Net tab.

Comment: I found that I get 404 Not Found error when I click continue button. index.php/pay/onepage/saveExcellence this is the address it tries to go to.

Comment: I believe your module's frontname is `pay`, controller name is `OnepageController` and method name is `saveExcellenceAction`, if it is then everything should work fine.

Comment: also i hope your Server Rewrites are turned off.

Comment: just `echo 'hi';exit;` in your `saveExcellenceAction` method's first line and execute. Lemme know what happens.

Comment: Yes I got it working, thanks :) As I said, my module's frontname was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the output of the ajax call that is made when you click 'continue'. You mayor nave some exception indica your code that gets cached by OPC. If that's the case, you should see a Json indicating the redirect as the ajax response.

Comment: i've checked errors with firebug, but nothing unordinary shows up.

Comment: What are you getting from the call? Please copy the response